# Mapbox toggle all layers off except one

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am new to Mapbox and javascript. I'm attempting to slightly modify a Mapbox GL code example, found [here](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/toggle-layers/), which allows for the toggling on/off of multiple layers.

I have four layers, and I would like the user to toggle these layers on and off, but when the map initially displays, I only want one layer toggled on. I am able to have three of the layers turned off when the page loads (here is one as an example):

```
 map.addSource("gnat-4zdrvs", {
     type: 'vector',
       url: 'mapbox://jesselangdon.bbtex1ps'
 });
 map.addLayer({
     "id": "gnat",
     "type": "line",
     "source": "gnat-4zdrvs",
     "source-layer": "gnat-4zdrvs",
     "minzoom": 8,
         "filter": [
             "==",
             "$type",
             "LineString"
        ],
        "layout": {
            "visibility": "none",
            "line-cap": "round",
            "line-join": "round"
        },
        "paint": {
            "line-width": 2,
            "line-color": {
                "base": 1,
                "type": "interval",
                "property": "C_Sin",
                "stops": [
                    [1,"hsl(189, 81%, 79%)"],
                    [1.02,"hsl(189, 91%, 65%)"],
                    [1.04, "hsl(189, 81%, 53%)"],
                    [1.06,"hsl(189, 83%, 43%)"],
                    [1.08,"hsl(189, 89%, 34%)"],
                    [1.1,"hsl(189, 90%, 28%)"],
                    [1.3,"hsl(189, 96%, 21%)"]
                ],
                "default": "hsl(0, 0%, 50%)"
            }
        }
   })
```

However, my limited knowledge of Javascript is keeping from figuring out how to set up the menu of clickable links so that only the `"visible"` layer is in a toggled "On" state.

Here's the code snippet which controls the toggle menu:

```
var toggleableLayerIds = [ 'conductivity', 'confinement', 'gnat', 'solar' ];

for (var i = 0; i < toggleableLayerIds.length; i++) {
    var id = toggleableLayerIds[i];

    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = '#';
    link.className = 'active';
    link.textContent = id;

    link.onclick = function (e) {
        var clickedLayer = this.textContent;
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        var visibility = map.getLayoutProperty(clickedLayer, 'visibility');

        if (visibility === 'visible') {
            map.setLayoutProperty(clickedLayer, 'visibility', 'none');
            this.className = '';
        } else {
            this.className = 'active';
            map.setLayoutProperty(clickedLayer, 'visibility', 'visible');
        }
    };

    var layers = document.getElementById('menu');
    layers.appendChild(link);
}
```

The map is viewable [here](https://southforkresearch.github.io/mapbox/index.html). Notice that all four layers in the toggle menu are blue (meaning they are in an "On" position, when in fact the only layer that is "on" is solar).  Any help, advice, or criticism is welcome... thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the class to active unconditionally on creation which will always make the link blue even if the layer is not visible. Try something like this.

```
    if(map.getLayoutProperty(id, 'visibility') === 'visible')
    {
     link.className = 'active';
    }
```

Though this will need to be done inside the onload function otherwise the property will be undefined.

Comment: It is only doing it during the onclick event but prior to any click event you are initializing the links class as active when you create them regardless of their associated layers visibility.

Comment: Sorry, deleted my poorly formatted comment.  So then could I just change link.className = 'active'; to link.className = '';

Comment: That would make them all white(off) regardless of visibility of the layer. The class should be set based on if the layer is visible or not.