# Mapbox on('load', function() shows data that should be hidden when I open the map

Tags: javascript, html, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have set the 'Student Comments' layer as initially hidden using a setLayoutProperty call as seen here

```html
map.on('load', function() {
map.setLayoutProperty('user-data-comments', 'visibility', 'none');
  map.setLayoutProperty('user-data-comments-text', 'visibility', 'none');
  });
```

However, when I open the interactive webmap, Mapbox displays the text before hiding it, when it should just appear hidden from the beginning. You can find the webmap [here](https://camilaandinod.github.io/Project-test/index.html). I'm not sure if this is a bug or I have to re-write my code somehow. You can find the source code [here](https://github.com/camilaandinod/Project-test/blob/master/index.html).

Let me know what you think.
Thanks!

Comment: you should move the layer creation logic to inside the load event

Comment: My code references layers created in mapbox studio, so I don’t have any later creation logic within the code itself. I am simply using java to toggle the existing layers on and off-please check the source code! @gvmani

Answer (score 0):

Sample taken from [https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/toggle-layers/] and modified

```js
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiY2FtaWxhYW5kaW5vIiwiYSI6ImNqMWlhbnlubDAxNHIyd2xtanQwZmZ3NTkifQ.QypsX075VYyKWFYilxAfxA';

var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
    zoom: 15,
    center: [-71.97722138410576, -13.517379300798098]
});

map.on('load', function () {
    map.addSource('museums', {
        type: 'vector',
        url: 'mapbox://mapbox.2opop9hr'
    });
   

    map.addSource('contours', {
        type: 'vector',
        url: 'mapbox://mapbox.mapbox-terrain-v2'
    });
    map.addLayer({
        'id': 'contours',
        'type': 'line',
        'source': 'contours',
        'source-layer': 'contour',
        'layout': {
            'visibility': 'visible',
            'line-join': 'round',
            'line-cap': 'round'
        },
        'paint': {
            'line-color': '#877b59',
            'line-width': 1
        }
    });
});

var toggleableLayerIds = [ 'contours', 'museums' ];

for (var i = 0; i < toggleableLayerIds.length; i++) {
    var id = toggleableLayerIds[i];

    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = '#';
    link.className = i==1 ? '' :'active';
    link.textContent = id;
    link.loaded = false;
    link.onclick = function (e) {
        var clickedLayer = this.textContent;
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
      if(this.loaded === false){
      this.loaded= true;
       map.addLayer({
        'id': 'museums',
        'type': 'circle',
        'source': 'museums',
        'layout': {
            'visibility': 'none'
        },
        'paint': {
            'circle-radius': 8,
            'circle-color': 'rgba(55,148,179,1)'
        },
        'source-layer': 'museum-cusco'
    });
      }
        var visibility = map.getLayoutProperty(clickedLayer, 'visibility');

        if (visibility === 'visible') {
            map.setLayoutProperty(clickedLayer, 'visibility', 'none');
            this.className = '';
        } else {
            this.className = 'active';
            map.setLayoutProperty(clickedLayer, 'visibility', 'visible');
        }
    };

    var layers = document.getElementById('menu');
    layers.appendChild(link);
}
```

```css
    #menu {
        background: #fff;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
        top: 10px;
        right: 10px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        width: 120px;
        border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    }

    #menu a {
        font-size: 13px;
        color: #404040;
        display: block;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        padding: 10px;
        text-decoration: none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
        text-align: center;
    }

    #menu a:last-child {
        border: none;
    }

    #menu a:hover {
        background-color: #f8f8f8;
        color: #404040;
    }

    #menu a.active {
        background-color: #3887be;
        color: #ffffff;
    }

    #menu a.active:hover {
        background: #3074a4;
    }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title>Show and hide layers</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.43.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.43.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <style>
        body { margin:0; padding:0; }
        #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>



<nav id="menu"></nav>
<div id="map"></div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you look at the link to my webmap? If you open it, you will see what I was referring to in the question immediately. When you open the link, the text from the comments layers appears for a second and then disappears- which I don't want to happen! (Open this: https://camilaandinod.github.io/Project-test/index.html) Also, what you are referring to here, I asked in another question- see here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48018703/mapbox-how-to-set-up-the-menu-so-that-only-the-visible-layers-are-in-an-on-s)

Comment: @CamilaAndino, it will be easier if you can update your style in the Studio and set the visibility property to none. Then in the click event it should be possible to change visibility as required.